# Fragments, Orientation Change and Fragment Backstacks

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation, back-stack

I currently have a layout which consists of a ContentPane and an ActionBarPane, each are containers for a `Fragment`.

Each ContentPane `Fragment` uses a Factory method to instantiate it's own ActionBarPane `Fragment` which leads to some pretty easy and quick development of complex `ActionBar`s.

```
public void setFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragmentName) {
    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.dualPaneActionBar, fragment.getActionBar(this));
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.dualPane, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(fragmentName);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

While this works fantastically well I've come across a bug concerning traversing the backstack after an orientation change.

My "back" implementation looks like this:

```
public void goBack() {
    if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 2){
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();            
    } else {
        // Actually Exit
    }
}
```

Which, `onBack()`, peels off both the ContentPane and it's ActionBar.

**The Problem:** When you get to a `Fragment Backstack` of 4 or more (2 ContentPanes and their ActionBars) and you change the orientation **then** `goBack()` the 2nd ActionBar is still present (the 3rd `Fragment` in the `Backstack`).

Without an orientation change, as expected, you end up with the correct ActionBar (`Fragment` 1) being presented.

Logging shows that `onBack()` starts with 4 `Fragment`s in the `Backstack`, each "pop" is called successfully and you end up with only 2 `Fragments` left (The original ContentPane and it's ActionBar).

Navigation forward and then backward correctly uses the original ActionBar not the one which was popped.

Does anybody have any knowledge of the process that happen to attached Fragments on Orientation Change and why this would cause such strange behaviour?

**EDIT**

```
for(int i =0; i < getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount(); i++) {
    Log.w("DualPaneActivity", getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName());    
}

getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

for(int i =0; i < getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount(); i++) {
    Log.w("DualPaneActivity", getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName());    
}
```

Gives output synonymous to:

```
Fragment1_actionbar, 
Fragment1, 
Fragment2_actionbar, 
Fragment2,

Fragment1_actionbar, 
Fragment1,
```

This output is the same when both the normal behaviour present's as well as when the incorrect behaviour presents...